# Convolution of randomly distributed data with gaussians

Tags: python, math, convolution

Lets say i have a randomly distributed data which looks like:

[image]

I want to replace each data point y[x_i] with fixed width gaussian
and add them together. It should give me:

[image]

My code is very primitive and slow:

```
def gaussian(x, mu, sig):
    return 1/(sig*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-np.power(x - mu, 2.) / (
        2 * np.power(sig, 2.)))

def gaussian_smoothing(x, y, sig=0.5, n=1000):

    x_new = np.linspace(x.min()-10*sig, x.max()+10*sig, n)
    y_new = np.zeros(x_new.shape)

    for _x, _y in zip(x, y):
        y_new += _y*gaussian(x_new, _x, sig)

    return x_new, y_new
```

For large data-sets it takes a long time to perform such smoothing.
I was looking at `np.convolve`. However it seams that that it is only applicable to evenly distributed data and x step for data and gaussians should be the same. What would be the fastest way to perform such operation.

Comment: "I want to replace each data point y[x_i] with fixed width gaussian and add them together." -- OK, this is called a kernel density model with a Gaussian kernel. There is probably already a kernel density function in a Python library (scipy / sklearn / numpy, I dunno, you'll have to check). A function in an existing library is probably optimized somewhat, but the fundamental limitation is that the number of Gaussian bumps is equal to the number of data. If the number of bumps is less, then it becomes a Gaussian mixture model, for which there is also probably a built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

yon try to estimate it as a Guassian mixture with smaller number of components (like EM algorithm) using `sklearn`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import choice
from sklearn import mixture
import scipy.stats
import numpy

# generate some data
x = numpy.array([1.,1.1,1.6,2.,2.1,2.2,2.9,3.,8.,62.,62.2,63.,63.4,64.5,65.,67.,69.])
# generate weights to it
y = numpy.random.rand(x.shape[0])
# normalize weigth to 1
y /= y.sum()  

# resamlple to 5000 samples with equal weights according to original weights
x_rsmp = numpy.array([choice(x, p=y) for _ in range(5000)])
x_rsmp.sort()
x_rsmp = x_rsmp.reshape(-1,1)

# define number of components - this must be user seelcted or estimated
n_comp = 2
# fit the mixture
gmm = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=n_comp, covariance_type='full')
gmm.fit(x_rsmp)

# plot it
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x_gauss = numpy.linspace(-10,100,1000)

for n_c in range(n_comp):
    norm_pdf = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x_gauss, gmm.means_[n_c,0], gmm.covariances_[n_c,0])
    ax.plot(x_gauss, norm_pdf, label='gauss %d' % (n_c+1))

ax.stem(x,y,'gray')
plt.legend()
```

It yields `n_c` Gaussian components with means `gmm.means_` and covariances `gmm.covariances_`.

[image]